# Panache Query in statement for Quarkus

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a method using a PanacheQuery where I am trying to combine several filters from a screen search into a single query for horses at a stable.  When I use just the horse name I get results as expected.  However when I add in the breed list, the list shows as null and i get no result even though I have confirmed the list is not empty.

Code block:

```
public List<Horse> find(Filter filter) {
      PanacheQuery<Horse> HorseResults = null;

      boolean isStarted = false;
      String query = "";
      Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(filter.getName())
            || null != filter.getHorseTypeList()) {
         if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(filter.getName())) {
            isStarted = true;
            query = " Name like :name ";
            params.put("name", filter.getName());
         }
         if (null != filter.getHorseTypeList()) {
            List<String> breedList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (HorseType name : filter.getHorseTypeList()) {
               breedList.add(name.toString());
            }
            if (isStarted) {
               query += " and ";
            }
            isStarted = true;
            query += " HorseType in (:horsetypes) ";
            System.out.println(breedList.size());
            params.put("horsetypes", breedList);
         }
         HorseResults = Horse.find(query, (Sort.by(filter.getSortBy().toString(), filter.getSortByDirection())),
               params);
      } else {
         HorseResults = Horse.findAll(Sort.by(filter.getSortBy().toString(), filter.getSortByDirection()));
      }

      return HorseResults.page(Page.of(filter.getPageNumber(), filter.getResultsPerPage())).list();
   }
```

Just horse name:

```
18:59:32 DEBUG [or.mo.dr.pr.command]] (executor-thread-0) Sending command '{"find": "HorseData", "filter": {"Name": {"$regex": "star"}}, "sort": {"MaxWeight": 1}, "limit": 25, "$db": "horseDB", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "qe4o2FnkQn+npdSp+O2f2Q==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 154 to database horseDB on connection [connectionId{localValue:24, serverValue:42}] to server 0.0.0.0:27018
```

When I use HorseType:

```
breedList Size: 2
19:06:15 DEBUG [io.qu.mo.pa.co.ru.MongoOperations]] (executor-thread-0) {'Name':{'$regex':'star'},'HorseType':{'$in':[null]}}
19:06:15 DEBUG [or.mo.dr.pr.command]] (executor-thread-0) Sending command '{"find": "HorseData", "filter": {"Name": {"$regex": "star"}, "HorseType": {"$in": [null]}}, "sort": {"MaxWeight": 1}, "limit": 25, "$db": "horseDB", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "p5Uo+3txTuCo/5M4YvgRQw==", "subType": "04"}}}}' with request id 195 to database horseDB on connection [connectionId{localValue:27, serverValue:45}] to server 0.0.0.0:27018
```

As you can see, the list is not empty.... it's just not being registered.  Not sure why at this point and looking for what I'm missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was corrected by removing the extra parenthesis around :horsetype.  Working line was

```
query += " HorseType in :horsetypes ";
```